# Make lightbox show up with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, popup, lightbox

I have a lightbox that is the user login. When they submit a form it checks if the user is logged in if not it needs to show the lightbox to let the user log in.

How can i do this out of the javascript.

This is the html code that makes the lightbox appear when the link is clicked.

```
<a href="#" class="popup-login">Login</a>
```

This is the javascipt i have so far, the else being when the user is not logged in. This is where i want the lightbox to show.

```
function islogin(){
    if(is_user_logged_in()){
        add_file_post();
    }else{

    }
}
```

Open login/registration via modal

UserPro has built-in support for modal or lightbox view which you can use
to display any of its shortcode, just like standard shortcodes.

*How to display the login form via modal or lightbox?*

You need a menu item or a custom HTML link that has this class:
*popup-login* That's it. An example should be:

```
<a href="#" class="popup-login">Login</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the prettiest way to do it, but you can try executing the click() function on the anchor element.

```
function islogin(){
  if(is_user_logged_in()){
    add_file_post();
  }else{
    jQuery('.popup-login').click();
  }
}
```